# How to include compass on the specified location on map using leaflet

Tags: angular, dictionary, leaflet, compass, bearing

How to put compass on specified location and point a certain bearing on location using angular and leaflet

Example below
[eg. example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMyQ7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-compass

I am not sure what you mean by location. Like attach the compass on the the map and sticky it to the map? Or on location in the viewport. For the latter you could use prop `position` and for the angle/bearing `angleOffset`.

Live example: https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-compass/examples/simple.html

Comment: example image to include compass on map like in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMyQ7.jpg maps can be street view or else.